# how to use partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. I have to show the names of interviewers from the table `interviews` in a partial view of interviewers. I am calling the `scheduled_interviews` as partial. How to do it? Am I doing this correctly?

Here's my code:

```
<%= render :partial=>"scheduled_interviews", :locals=>{
  :interviews=>Interview.find(:interviewer_name=>@interviewers.name)
}%>
```

Comment: Looks like you are doing it all wrong read the guide, its a rails gold mine
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: In case you didn't know, you should accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the partial name is `_scheduled_interviews.htm.erb` for example then calling the partial will be `<%= render :partial => "scheduled_interviews" %>`. If you want to pass some parameters to the partial then use the locals attribute as you mentioned in the question `render :partial => "scheduled_interviews", :locals=> {:interviews => Interview.find_by_interviewer_name(@interviewer.name)}` to pass a collection (for example an array you could use the `:collection` parameter. I highly recommend you read the following [tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)